# Error pulling docker image from GCR: "You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials."

Tags: gcloud

I am SSH'd into a GCE instance in Project A whose service account has Storage Admin access in Project B, where Image Foo is located. When I run docker build . from the command line of my GCE instance, I get the above error when docker tries to pull Image Foo from Project B. I have configured docker according to the instructions in the link, and authenticated using gcloud.

Comment: *the instructions in the link* Could you please add this link in the question so we can look at it?

Comment: @DazWilkin's answer should be accepted. gcloud auth configure-docker did the trick for me. But before that I had to install docker, add my user to the docker group and reboot my machine.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's one or two of two things:

First, check which account you're running under on the VM (`gcloud auth list`). It's probably the VM's service account not your user account. This is the account that needs to be IAM'd to the bucket;

Second, ensure you've configured docker to access the account's credentials for GCR (if possible: `gcloud auth configure-docker`).

Then, it should work.

I repro'd your error and applied these changes and it works (link)